# Why would eggs have blue in them?

Tags: food-safety, eggs

Recently when I scrambled some eggs, I noticed some bright blue patches inside the eggs. Not around the outside, but when I took a bite out of part of one there was a bright blue patch in the uneaten half.

It wasn't even a natural, mold sort of blue, but looked almost like dye. But I didn't notice anything when I first cracked the egg. One of my friends has had a similar experience. How could this happen?

I discarded the rest of the eggs, but would they have been safe to eat?

Answer (score 6):

With boiled eggs, the yolk can get a blue/green tint, particularly when over-cooked or cooked at too high a temp a reaction most of us have seen.  It is a reaction between sulfur and iron.  The same can occur with scrambled eggs.  Over cooking and cooking at high temperature is considered a prime culprit.  Cooking in iron reportedly increases the likelihood as it increases the available iron for the reaction.  If the eggs are old, or if the birds have had a diet that resulted in a bit more sulfur in the yolk it might be more likely.